# How to get the daily amount of committed transactions on a given MSSQL database?

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log, audit, reporting

The number of transactions for the current connection can be obtained with @@TRANCOUNT.

How can you get a daily counter of the globally committed transactions on a given database?

Comment: You need that in the future (from now on) or in the past (you need to check data for yesterday for example)?

Comment: In the past, I need to report transaction volume for mesasurement against the agreed service level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Below is a great script from Paul's blog  [Script: open transactions with text and plans](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/script-open-transactions-with-text-and-plans/)which should get you going:

```
SELECT
    [s_tst].[session_id],
    [s_es].[login_name] AS [Login Name],
    DB_NAME (s_tdt.database_id) AS [Database],
    [s_tdt].[database_transaction_begin_time] AS [Begin Time],
    [s_tdt].[database_transaction_log_bytes_used] AS [Log Bytes],
    [s_tdt].[database_transaction_log_bytes_reserved] AS [Log Rsvd],
    [s_est].text AS [Last T-SQL Text],
    [s_eqp].[query_plan] AS [Last Plan]
FROM
    sys.dm_tran_database_transactions [s_tdt]
JOIN
    sys.dm_tran_session_transactions [s_tst]
ON
    [s_tst].[transaction_id] = [s_tdt].[transaction_id]
JOIN
    sys.[dm_exec_sessions] [s_es]
ON
    [s_es].[session_id] = [s_tst].[session_id]
JOIN
    sys.dm_exec_connections [s_ec]
ON
    [s_ec].[session_id] = [s_tst].[session_id]
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    sys.dm_exec_requests [s_er]
ON
    [s_er].[session_id] = [s_tst].[session_id]
CROSS APPLY
    sys.dm_exec_sql_text ([s_ec].[most_recent_sql_handle]) AS [s_est]
OUTER APPLY
    sys.dm_exec_query_plan ([s_er].[plan_handle]) AS [s_eqp]
ORDER BY
    [Begin Time] ASC;
GO
```

You can schedule it accordingly via job to send you the results as per you're needs:

2) Also, you can refer to [Adam Mechanic's WHO_IS_ACTIVE](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2009/12/03/who-is-active-v9-57-fast-comprehensive-dmv-collection.aspx) to get the details for same.

To gather the data from who_is_active you can log that to a table for later review as explained here [How to Log Activity Using sp_whoisactive in a Loop](http://www.brentozar.com/responder/log-sp_whoisactive-to-a-table/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already know WHO_IS_ACTIVE and probably it's the best way to go about it because it's already prepared to save results into tables.

Comment: Ok, @KASQLDBA, but this will give you result in the future and you need to check data from the past? Or I am missing something?